# How to break a line in text caption with Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, histogram

I’m currently designing a chart using the following LaTeX structure:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) grid[xstep=20,ystep=1] (10.8,6);
\draw [line width=6mm, color=blue!50] plot [ycomb] coordinates {(1,5.7) (2,5.4) (3,2.1) (4,1.9) (5,1.2) (6,1.2) (7,1) (8,0.9) (9,0.8) (10,0.8) };

% SCALE 
\draw (-0.75,0) node{0};
\draw (-0.75,1) node{5};
\draw (-0.75,2) node{10};
\draw (-0.75,3) node{15};
\draw (-0.75,4) node{20};
\draw (-0.75,5) node{25};
\draw (-0.75,6) node{30};

\draw(1,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text };
\draw (2,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text \& Text};
\draw (3,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text};
\draw (4,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text};
\draw (5,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text \\ Text};
\draw (6,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text \\ Text};
\draw (7,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text};
\draw (8,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text \& \\ Text};
\draw (9,-1) node[rotate=45]{Text Text};
\draw (10,-1) node[rotate=45]{text};

\draw[white] (1,5.2) node{0.9};
\draw[white] (2,4.9) node{6.4};
\draw[white] (3,1.6) node{4};
\draw[white] (4,1.5) node{2.8};
\draw[white] (5,0.9) node{4.7}; 
\draw[white] (6,0.9) node{0.9};
\draw[white] (7,0.7) node{6.4};
\draw[white] (8,0.6) node{4};
\draw[white] (9,0.55) node{2.8};
\draw[white] (10,0.55) node{4.7};  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I tried to use classical line break instruction like `\\` and also `\` in some text part but without success. I found a lot of solutions but they require the use of `\node`. In my text part all the instructions already begin with `\draw` that I would like to conserve. How can I break a line text in my case with `\node{}`?

Comment: Add `text width` inside node options and `\\\`  will work inside the node contents.

Comment: [text width] essentially puts the text into a \parbox.  ]alaign=...] essentially puts the text into a tabular.

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved :  \draw(1,-1) node[rotate=45,**text width = 3cm**]{Text \\ Text};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in comments by Ignasi: *"Add `text width` inside node options and `\\` will work inside the node contents."*